# Getting the non common elements from the two columns in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data1 = {'date': ['1998', '1999','1999','2000','1999'], 
        'node1': [1,1,2,3,3],
     'node2': [3,4,3,4,8],
     'weight': [1,1,1,1,1], }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['date', 'node1','node2','weight'])

data2 = {'date': ['2002','2001','2003','2002','2002','2001'], 
        'node1': [1,1,1,2,2,3],
     'node2': [2,3,4,3,5,4],
     'weight': [1,1,1,1,1,1], }
df2= pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['date', 'node1','node2','weight'])
```

I would like to search both the columns in each dataframe and then output the row which has the non common element in it.

Output for this data would be:

dataframe1: 3 8 1999

dataframe2: 2 5 2002

Output explanation-By searching across the two rows in the two dataframes we find that 5 and 8 are the non common elements therefore the row containing them are printed.

Edit-Data corrected.

Comment: Please look at your data again, it's not reflecting your expected output.

Comment: Non-unique rows by which columns?

Comment: searching in both the columns

Comment: @coldspeed Could you explain what is wrong with the data?Thanks

Comment: For starters, your variable names are wrong. You define data1/data2 but pass data. Secondly, one of your arrays in df1 is missing data. Thirdly, your output does not reflect your explanation. Wha do you mean by "non-unique" elements? How is 3 8 1999 non unique?

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks a lot!I corrected these.What I mean by non-common is that 8 and 5 are the only elements which are not present in both the dataframe rows.

Comment: `'1998'` is not present in both df's rows..?

Comment: It is searching by the node1 node2 columns and then displaying the rows where the node is found.

Comment: @Vaishali we search for non common elements in both the rows of the two dataframes Here it is 5 and 8

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ data corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this probably isn't the best answer but it works:

```
dfs = pd.concat([df1, df2])
nodes = pd.concat([dfs['node1'], dfs['node2']])
counts = nodes.value_counts()
unique = []

for index, value in zip(counts.index, counts.tolist()):
    if value == 1:
        unique.append(index)

unique_df1 = df1[(df1['node1'].isin(unique)) | ((df1['node2'].isin(unique)))]
unique_df2 = df2[(df2['node1'].isin(unique)) | ((df2['node2'].isin(unique)))]

print(unique_df1)
print(unique_df2)
```

Output:

```
   date  node1  node2  weight
4  1999      3      8       1
   date  node1  node2  weight
4  2002      2      5       1
```

Comment: How to Know which row is from which dataframe?

Comment: @ChaitaliSarkar. You can write it as two separate lines, and that way you know which one is which. See the update above